# Custom options for bundle products in Magento

Tags: magento, bundle

Does anyone know any technical reasons as why bundle products with dynamic pricing cannot have custom options?

Comment: Can you kindly explain your question in detail please?

Comment: When you I try to add custom option to bundle product in Magento "Bundle with dynamic pricing cannot include custom defined options. Options will not be saved." error message appears.